# Find all linear transformations $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ that satisfy the following:

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I am currently taking a course on linear algebra and we are studying linear transformations. In an exercise, we are asked the following:

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ let $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ with $e_1 = (1,0,0)$, $e_2 = (0,1,0)$ and $e_3 = (0,0,1)$, be a basis. Find all matrices of the linear transformations
\begin{equation*}
f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3
\end{equation*}
that satisfy

1. $Ker(f) = \langle e_1 + e_2 \rangle$.
2. $f(e_3) = e_2 - e_3$.
3. $f(v) \in \langle v \rangle$, being $v = 2e_1 + e_2 + e_3$.

Which of them verify $Im(f^2) \neq Im(f)$?

I don't know how to find $ALL$ of them or how to impose that they satisfy that and then find them.

Comment: Yes, exactly, may I edit it?

Comment: Try it only when (1) holds. Hint: look at the subspace orthogonal to the line trough $(1, 1, 0)$ and $O$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{B} = \{e_1 + e_2, e_3, 2e_1 + e_2 + e_3\}$ is a basis. You know the values of $f$ on that basis:

\begin{align}
f(e_1 + e_2) &= 0 \\
f(e_3) &= e_2 - e_3 \tag{$*$}\label{equations} \\
f(2e_1 + e_2 + e_3) &= t(2e_1 + e_2 + e_3)
\end{align}

(for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$). Remember: the linear transformation $f$ is determined uniquely by its values on some basis.

So if $\mathcal{S} = \{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ denotes the standard basis, then

$$ [f]^{\mathcal{S}}_\mathcal{B} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2t \\ 0 & 1 & t \\ 0 & -1 & t\end{bmatrix}. $$

Use this to find $[f]^\mathcal{S}_\mathcal{S}$. You can figure out what the image is directly from the equations \eqref{equations}.

Comment: But this gives a linear transformation from $\mathcal{B}$, doesn't it? How can you find its values in the original basis (i.e the standard basis)? Performing a change of basis?

Comment: @UriToti Yes, you need to do a change of basis. Just be careful because I wrote down the matrix going from $\mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{S}$ not from $\mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{B}$ so you only need to do "half" of the change of basis if that makes sense. You need to write down the identity transformation going from $\mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Yes, I think I got it. 

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$
Times the final matrix you got?

Comment: @UriToti you want the inverse of that matrix. So that matrix takes B to S right? Because the first column is the first element of B expressed in the basis S.

Comment: Yes sorry that was what I meant, I forgot the $^{-1}$.